# How can I find out why I can't connect to a WLAN?

Tags: networkmanager, wlan

I can connect to a WLAN with ESSID `75% Internet` with my laptop, but not with my desktop computer (it also works with my smartphone, but not on my tablet). I can see the WLAN with `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`, but not with `iwlist wlan0 scan`.
(On my laptop I can see it without superuser rights)

How can I figure out why I can't connect to the network?

It seems not to be a driver problem, because I can see the ESSID (right?). But I don't know how to get any more feedback. Are too many devices in the WLAN? Is my MAC address blocked? Is the WLAN card of the desktop computer too weak? Is there some other misconfiguration on my desktop / tablet?
(By the way: I can login with the tablet at university, so in principle the WLAN of the tablet works. But not with that specific network)

### My System

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 17 Qiana \n \l

$ uname -a
Linux pc09 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:1F:3F:10:85:C7
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"75% Internet"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000D3530252050617274797A6F6E65
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0107
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A0800280101000200FF0F
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: 34:31:C4:0A:A8:19
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"easybell DSL"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C6561737962656C6C2044534C
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706444520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0102
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF111BFFFFFF00000000000000000001000000000406E6470D00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0C00040E010102010000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD6F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001023B98D96D9E54CF961DE3431C40AA8191021000341564D1023000446426F78102400043030303010420004303030301054000800060050F20400011011000446426F78100800022788103C0001031049000600372A000120
```

Comment: Can you mention the Linux distro for the desktop? What type of tablet is this too?

Comment: It is an android tablet. The distribution is Linux Mint (which is based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian).

Comment: Have you configured NetworkManager to use the Connection?

Comment: I have entered the password via NetworkManager the same way on my desktop as I did on my notebook.